# Fetch Datetime type data from SQL Server to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, datetime

I am having a problem in fetching data into variable in c# from SQL Server.

Here is my code.

```
SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BROWN-PC\KAZIM;Initial Catalog=Agency;Integrated Security=True");

string lastlogt;
string lastlogd;

myCon.Open();

SqlCommand cd2 = new SqlCommand(" SELECT TOP 1 * From (select Top 2 * from Agency.dbo.lastlogindt ORDER BY uid DESC) x ORDER BY uid",myCon);

SqlDataReader sdr;
sdr = cd2.ExecuteReader();
while (sdr.Read()) {
    lastlogd = sdr.GetString(2);
    lastlogt = sdr.GetString(3);

}

myCon.Close();
Dates.Text = lastlogd;
timing.Text = lastlogt;
```

Now the problem is that the columns of SQL Server from which I'm taking data is of `date` and `time` datatypes. and the error I am facing is

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `GetDateTime` and `GetTimeSpan` methods:

```
while (sdr.Read()) 
{
     lastlogd = sdr.GetDateTime(2);
     lastlogt = sdr.GetTimeSpan(3);
}
```

There are other methods for various data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Datetime' to 'string' .

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's working now.
lastlogd = sdr.GetDateTime(2).ToShortDateString();
lastlogt = sdr.GetTimeSpan(3).ToString();

I just wanted to know if I could change the time format from 24 to 12 hour.?